# sort by tags with weight in mongodb and maybe redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, redis

I am trying to list items according to how 'important' their tags are.

Here is an example of an item:

```
{
    name: 'item1',
    tags: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

And here is an example of a tag

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: red,
    weight: 0.7
}
```

I am trying to find out the best way to sort a list of items where a lot of calculations must be made.

I imagine that sorting in real time might not be the best way and resorting to something like redis might be necessary.
By doing so I would store all the data relevant to calculate the sorting positions in redis right ?

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't do cross-collection work in MongoDB (you can't from a single query get the `weight` from a different collection while iterating through the `item`s). So, if you're planning on structuring your data this way, you'll need to find a different technique. MongoDB may not be suitable for your requirements.

Comment: use sorted-sets in redis. keep the score as a weight and your item as a key. You can sort in realtime.

Comment: Question aside, I would be interested to see how you derive a score from your tag weights.